# How did the Time Lords put a whole "Star" in a Tardis?

Tags: doctor-who, tardis

How did the Time Lords put a whole "Star" in a Tardis?

Do they have some kind of galaxy shrinking technology or what do they use?

[image: Star inside of the Tardis]

Comment: Have you not noticed that it's bigger on the inside?

Comment: It's ***much*** bigger on the inside

Comment: Could it be possible that they “created” an artificial star inside the infinite TARDIS? After all, they did do it for the Eye of Harmony (an artificial black girl created by the Time Lords)

Comment: You probably need to purchase the deluxe Hand of Omega bundle. :)

Comment: @Shreedhar - Black hole.

Comment: Damnit!!! This is why I don’t like to use sff on phone. Damn autocorrect. ‍♂️‍♂️‍♂️

Comment: Patiently. After all, they had plenty of time.

Comment: *Very carefu—* oh, forget it.

Comment: Keep in mind that there's a reason the show is called Doctor Who and not Doctor How

Comment: Possible Duplicate https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/10139/how-do-timelords-create-interiors-that-are-larger-than-the-exterior

Answer (score 15):

Time and **Relative Dimensions** In Space - TARDIS

We've seen plenty of episodes where the TARDIS is enormous. In fact, the episode [The Name of the Doctor](https://tardis.fandom.com/wiki/The_Name_of_the_Doctor_(TV_story)) gives us a hint that it's not just bigger on the inside, it's HUGE ([size leak](https://tardis.fandom.com/wiki/Size_leak))

[image: Size leak TARDIS]

The catch here is that's not **just** a star, it's a collapsing star. From [Journey to the Centre of the TARDIS](http://www.chakoteya.net/DoctorWho/33-11.htm)

> DOCTOR: The Eye of Harmony. Exploding star in the act of becoming a black hole. Time Lord engineering. You rip the star from its orbit, suspend it in a permanent state of decay.

This type of star is called a [Eye of Harmony](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eye_of_Harmony). The Doctor's version is a mere copy, with the original residing on Gallifrey. Apparently Rassilon was capable of such a feat

> According to the ancient records, the legendary Time Lord Rassilon captured and placed the Eye – the nucleus of a black hole – beneath the Time Lord's citadel on Gallifrey (the Panopticon). Rassilon placed the black hole's nucleus in an eternally dynamic equation against the mass of Gallifrey and so that as long as the Eye existed in this "balanced state", the power of the Time Lords would "neither flux nor wither". However, it remained there so long that it passed into legend.

As was Omega

> Omega was a solar engineer who, in trying to provide an energy source for the Time Lords' time travel experiments, harnessed the power of a supernova.

From [The Satan Pit](http://www.chakoteya.net/DoctorWho/28-9.htm)

> DOCTOR: I'm just towing you home. Gravity schmavity. My people practically invented black holes. Well, in fact, they did.

The implication is that these ancient Time Lords knew how to manipulate gravity and space in fantastic ways. As such, moving a star into something the size of a phone booth would have been trivial.

Comment: It's Omega that made the original. Rassilon just used the result.